# Georeferencing with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, avenza

In QGIS 2.18.11, I am using the Print Composer to generate a TIF file, which I am subsequently using as input to generate a Georeferenced TIF with the Raster Conversion Translate facility to get my output. My goal is to have a georeferenced map that I can load into Avenza maps. It loads and georeferences, but the location of my map shows it as being 216 miles away, rather than the 11 miles that it actually is.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I've looked up a CRS for my area (EPSG:2264) and used the same CRS that I use in my base main QGIS window and the translator. When I try to use EPSG:3857, the Geo TIF doesn't show up as georeferenced. I've had the same difficulty of being approximately 200 miles off with other CRS for my area as well.

Comment: What is the CRS of the QGIS map view that you are creating the TIF from?  Are the problems you are encountering with the map display in Avenza?  Also, I have used the Print Composer export as image to output a geotiff in one step.  You just have to remember to set the reference map in composition tab to the composer map frame containing the map (I think this is by default not set).  I am using QGIS 2.18.16.